# Comformal color mapping of images of two variable complex functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have plotted a the image of a two-variable complex function in the Argand plane, but I would like to use color to see where in the input space the points of that image came from.

I colored the Argand plane (input space):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

a = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)
b = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)

A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)

fx = np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.pcolormesh(A,B, fx)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Yielding:
[colored plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQjZ.png)

Then, I created my function and mapped its image:

```
y = np.exp(1j*A) - np.exp(-1j*B)

real = y.real
# extract imaginary part using numpy
imag = y.imag
  
# plot the complex numbers
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(real, imag, '--r*')
#plt.pcolormesh(cmap=fx)

plt.xlim(-2.05, 2.05)
plt.ylim(-2.05, 2.05)
plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
plt.xlabel('Real')
plt.show()
```

Yielding:
[Image plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTaH3.png)

I would like to color match these two, so I would be able to tell where the points on my image came from. So, for instance, output points that came from near the origin would show up as dark blue on my complex image mapping.

My idea was to loop through the set of points in the image and have them take on the same color as the input point that yielded them. But (1) I am not sure how to find the color of the input points in the first place, and (2) I don't even know if that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), that accepts an array for the color:

```
c: array-like or list of colors or color, optional
The marker colors. Possible values:
* A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
* A 2D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.
* A sequence of colors of length n.
* A single color format string.
```

This is how it'd look like:
[image: scatter plot with an array for color]

And the code:

```
import numpy as np
# import sympy as sym
# import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline 

a = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)
b = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.1)

A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)

fx = np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,5))
ax1.pcolormesh(A,B, fx)
# ax1.colorbar()

y = np.exp(1j*A) - np.exp(-1j*B)

real = y.real
# extract imaginary part using numpy
imag = y.imag

# plot the complex numbers
ax2.scatter(real, imag, c=fx, s=7, edgecolor='k', linewidths=0.1)
#plt.pcolormesh(cmap=fx)

ax2.set_xlim(-2.05, 2.05)
ax2.set_ylim(-2.05, 2.05)
ax2.set_ylabel('Imaginary')
ax2.set_xlabel('Real')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is awesome Filipe! I'd upvote you if I could, but I don't have the reputation :p

It may not be quite what I want, but it is a step in the right direction. My only concern with scatter plots is, would I be able to answer questions on the levels of curves, like, "what happens to the imaginary axis under this transformation?"

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that works for you. Maybe you can accept as the answer? (I'm also not too familiar)
I'm not sure how the lines would help. You could either add an `ax.plot` with a single color on the back, or do something more complicated like [this multicolored line plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).